# How to deploy Angular and Socket.io Application?

Tags: angular, deployment, socket.io, hosting, web-deployment

I have created an Angular application which uses Sockets. I tried to deploy it on Firebase but its not working there. How should I deploy my application?

Comment: Not enough information here. What is not working, how did you implement sockets on the serverside? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.